# Consuming IEnumerable in parallel with a fixed number of Tasks/Threads

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a source `IEnumerable<T>` which I would like to process in a parallel way having a fixed number of tasks/threads (close to the number of processors) each of them grabbing the next item from the source and process it until all the elements have been iterated.

- `Parallel.For` is not a candidate as the number of elements is unknown.
- `Parallel.ForEach` is not a candidate because is creates many Tasks even when specifying `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` as this parameter only ensures the maximum number of tasks running concurrently but not the number of tasks created.
- Each Task must be notified that the source is traversed until its end so it can run some wrapping up logic.
- The elements of the source list cannot be held in memory but must be processed and discarded continuously.

Sounds like a producer/consumer problem with the simplification that the producer can be single-threaded and once the IEnumerable is finished, no more element will be added.

How would a solution for this problem look like using the TPL? Do I have to implement my own shareable thread-safe `IEnumerable` or does the framework provide something?

EDIT: this is my try with `Parallel.ForEach` and specifying `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` which does not prevent the TPL to create many tasks.

```
int nbTasks = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(positions, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
    () => { return new List<IPositionData>(); },
    (position, loop, list) =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        list.Add(position);
        return list;
     },
     list => Interlocked.Add(ref nbTasks, 1));
Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Tasks: {0}", nbTasks));
```

Comment: `positions` is my source `IEnumerable<IPositionData>`. I've just ran this and for example, nbTasks is 64 (and not the expected 4 on my 4 cores).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can limit the number of tasks in `Parallel.ForEach` by using an overload that expects a `ParallelOptions` object and setting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` property.

Comment: I've tried exactly this with no success. Although I specify MaxDegreeOfParallelism to for example 4, much more Tasks are being created than 4. I guess, this is due to initialization which is not solely CPU bound. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @Dejan Could you show us a bit of your code? I've just tried a simple example and I can verify in my case `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` works correctly.

Comment: @Dejan I see your issue; `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` only ensures the number of concurrent tasks does not exceed your total, it does not limit the number of tasks created. Would it be possible for you to modify your `localInit` lambda to reuse the result of your complex initialization between subsequent tasks? You'd have to perform at most `Environment.ProcessorCount` initializations then. If not, you'd probably need to write your own `TaskScheduler`.

Comment: Alternatively - do use a `Parellel.For` but not on the number of items, but on the number of concurrent tasks you want to create. Then you'd just need to synchronize access to your enumerator.

Comment: Ah, that's a good one to know - now I understand `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, thanks. But all-in-all this leads as back to my original question. Do I have to implement my one synchronized enumerator or custom scheduler or does the framework provide something out-of-the-box to cover my scenario.

Comment: I don't believe it does - however, synchronized access to an enumerator shouldn't be a big deal (e.g. use the enumerator manually by calling `MoveNext` / `CurrentPosition` and ensure both are in a sync block).

Answer (score 0):

You can limit number of tasks in `Parallel.ForEach`:

```
   in maxNumberOfTasks = 4;
   Parallel.ForEach(collection, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxNumberOfTasks}, 
                 i => {
                        //Your action here
                  });
```